# Tabbar controller unexpected dismiss behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with two childs (A and B) and I present a third controller C from `UITabBarController` but if I call dismiss on controller A, controller C gets dismissed.

How can this happen even if controller C is not part of controller A's hierarchy? If this is the default behavior can I change it?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let tab = UITabBarController()
        let a = A()
        let b = B()
        tab.viewControllers = [a, b]
        window?.rootViewController = tab
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+5) {
            tab.present(C(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        return true
    }
}

class A: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+10) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```